# REST API Salesforce get company information?

Tags: rest-api, language

REST API Salesforce get company information?

does such endpoint exist? especially, interested in Language Settings https://yadi.sk/i/Ro3btZUS3SDKA2

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you elaborate?  To use the REST API, you need to create your own endpoint with an APEX Class that responds to the HttpGet/HttpPost request.

Answer (score 4):

You can query the [Organization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm) table to get at that information.

```
/services/data/v42.0/query?q=SELECT+LanguageLocaleKey+FROM+Organization
```

Sample output:

```
{
  "totalSize" : 1,
  "done" : true,
  "records" : [ {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Organization",
      "url" : "/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Organization/00D..."
    },
    "LanguageLocaleKey" : "en_US"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to grab the list of company profile languages https://yadi.sk/i/Ro3btZUS3SDKA2 ?